# Get LAST_INSERT_ID from transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dapper

I have the following code:

```
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(this.connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (MySqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var r = connection.Execute(@"INSERT INTO tableA (`listId`, `parentListId`, `name`, `userId`)
                            VALUES
                            (NULL, @parentListId, @name, @userId);

                            INSERT INTO `tableA_misc` (`listId`, `userId`, `permissions`)
                            VALUES
                            (LAST_INSERT_ID(), @ownerId, 'Read');

                            SELECT CAST(LAST_INSERT_ID() AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);",
                        new {
                            parentListId = _parentListId,
                            name = _name,
                            userId = _currentUser.user_id
                        }, transaction);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
```

How can I retrieve `the LAST_INSERT_ID()` since `r` only returns the number of rows that were inserted?

Thank you

Comment: Try changing .Execute to .Query<T>

Comment: @VoidRay Yup, that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to this fixed:

```
 using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(this.connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (MySqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var lastId = connection.Query<int>(@"INSERT INTO tableA (`listId`, `parentListId`, `name`, `userId`)
                            VALUES
                            (NULL, @parentListId, @name, @userId);

                            INSERT INTO `tableA_misc` (`listId`, `userId`, `permissions`)
                            VALUES
                            (LAST_INSERT_ID(), @ownerId, 'Read');

                            SELECT CAST(LAST_INSERT_ID() AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);",
                        new {
                            parentListId = _parentListId,
                            name = _name,
                            userId = _currentUser.user_id
                        }, transaction);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
            }
```